# Ajax Autocomplete With Comma in Data

Tags: asp.net, ajax, autocomplete, autocompleteextender

Situation is straight forward.  I have a textbox with ajax autocomplete extender.  Data that comes back as user types is simple:   Last Name , First Name

My issue is that i need for users to be able to type the "," comma that separates the names.

This is so they can narrow down the candidate data by First Name...
Example:

Smith, Able
Smith, Baker
Smith, Charlie

Problem is as soon as I type a "," the list of data disappears.   I tried taking "," out of the delimiters tag, but that didn't work.

I only need to be able to select a single entry, not multiple.
Any idea on how I can allow the entry of the "," and have the autocomplete continue on?

Comment: Could you please post the query method you are using to return the values?

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "select emp.UserId, (ISNULL(emp.NameLast,'') + ', ' + ISNULL(emp.NameFirst,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(emp.NameInitial,''))  as EmpName from employee.dbo.tblEmployees emp Where" & _
            " UserId is NOT NULL and" & _
            " emp.NameLast LIKE @SearchText + '%'"
        '
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefixText)

..Then this is used when looping thru recs
            Dim item As String = AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender.CreateAutoCompleteItem(sdr("EmpName").ToString, sdr("UserId").ToString)
            employees.Add(item)

Comment: Nevermind!  I kind of figured it out...In the jumbled query above...i was ONLY searching on last name.  I should have been searching on the concatenated lastname/first name.